# AWS IAM and CLI - How to resolve pass role error?

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-cli

I logged into AWS console as DEV-OPS-ENGINEER and created ROLE-1 with aws managed policy attached. I attached this role to ECS tasks.

Now from my machine I logged into aws cli as DEVELOPER and ran aws ecs update-service command but i am getting below mentioned error:

"An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the UpdateService operation: User: arn:aws:sts:::assumed-role/DEVELOPER is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam:::role/ROLE-1"

My idea was all logged in user (with different roles) should be able to use ROLE-1.

Any idea why it is throwing me this error and how can I resolve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a role (and its permissions) to an AWS service, a user must have permissions to pass the role to the service. This helps administrators ensure that only approved users can configure a service with a role that grants permissions. To allow a user to pass a role to an AWS service, you must grant the PassRole permission to the user's IAM user, role, or group.

Find out more, including examples, in the AWS User Guide: [Granting a user permissions to pass a role to an AWS service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_passrole.html)